# Relationship between a class of non-linear differential equations and algebraic geometry.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-geometry

I was just thinking about non-linear differential equations of a single variable, $F(f(x))=0$ that are polynomial in the derivatives of $f$.  For example:

$$ 2\left(\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}\right)^5 - \frac{1}{7}\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2  + \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = 0$$

This can be considered as a polynomial in three variables, $x,y,$ and $z$:

$$ 2x^5 - \frac{1}{7}y^2  + z = 0$$

This polynomial has a set of roots that has various properties which it derives from algebraic geometry, and my question is: Can someone explain what sort of things from algebraic geometry influence the solution set of the original differential equation?

Thanks!

P.S. I found [this](http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~ksda/PostedPapers/pjcalggroups.pdf), but it's a pretty hard paper so it's gonna take awhile to work through anything, is this paper relevant to my question?

Comment: Can you explain the various properties which are of interest?  The interaction between algebraic geometry and diff eq is quite large.

Comment: @MathEE: Is there a link you could recommend by any chance to get started?

Comment: @MattCalhoun Do you understand, first and foremost, the link between topology and diff eqs? For example, do you understand the monodromy action?

Comment: I think I am not sure if you are looking for a "hard" answer or a "soft" answer.  Do you want links to large texts from a variety of approaches or do you just want a feeling for why algebraic geometry shows up?